# Questions on Support for ICP on IaaS question?

Tags: ibm-information-server

If I want to deploy on Amazon IaaS, I could deploy directly with our containerized release IIS deploying its own K8s/docker environment. However, if we wanted to lay down ICP first on Amazon IaaS, and then install DataStage (ultimately IISEE next release) - is this supported? My customer is only interested in moving IISEE to Amazon IaaS - but most run in containers.

Answer (score 0):

DataStage dockers can be deployed on Azure/AWS
with AKS(Azure) and EKS(AWS)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.install.doc/topics/c_prep_aws_azure.html